# Path test versus iterated limits for proving existence of a limit

Tags: analysis, limits, multivariable-calculus

Which is the strongest method for proving existence of limits (or the non-existence of a limit), the path test or using iterated limits?

Indeed, there are cases where the iterated limit shows that the limit exists, but then using the path test and setting a particular "path", it can be shown that the limit actually does NOT exist. Which is right, and which is wrong? How should one choose which method to use in any case of finding whether a limit exists?

Comment: If I understand what you mean by iterated limits correctly, that method is only valid once you've proved some sufficient conditions, for example if the function were continuous at that point.

Comment: If it is continuous at that point, doesn't that imply from the definition of continuity itself that the limit exists?